# Laravel: How can i access data in two different models in one controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a records page where the pages shows the student records. This record will comprise of the **student's name**, which will be taken from the `users database` and the **course name**, taken from the `courses database`. now how can I do this. Below is the code i have tried but doesn't work.

**srcontroller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Course;

class SRController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $records = User::all(),Course::all();
        return view('records.index')->with('records', $records);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**records.index blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @if (count($records)>0)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Course Major</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($records as $record)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$account->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$account->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$course->course_name}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    @else

    @endif
@endsection
```

**accounts controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserAccountsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $accounts = User::all();
        return view('users.index')->with('accounts', $accounts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('users.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'acctyp'=>'required',
            'name'=>'required',
            'surname'=>'required',
            'gender'=>'required',
            'dob'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'userid'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required',
        ]);

        $account = new User;
        $account->acctyp = $request->input('acctyp');
        $account->name = $request->input('name');
        $account->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $account->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $account->dob = $request->input('dob');
        $account->email = $request->input('email');
        $account->userid = $request->input('userid');
        $account->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $account->save();

        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'New user successfully added!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $account = User::find($id);
        return view('users.show')->with('account', $account);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $account = User::find($id);
        return view('users.edit')->with('account', $account);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'acctyp'=>'required',
            'name'=>'required',
            'surname'=>'required',
            'gender'=>'required',
            'dob'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'userid'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required',
        ]);

        $account = User::find($id);
        $account->acctyp = $request->input('acctyp');
        $account->name = $request->input('name');
        $account->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $account->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $account->dob = $request->input('dob');
        $account->email = $request->input('email');
        $account->userid = $request->input('userid');
        $account->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $account->save();

        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'User successfully updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $account = User::find($id);
        $account->delete();

        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'User successfully removed!');
    }
}
```

**courses controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Course;

class CoursesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $courses = Course::all();
        return view('subs.index')->with('courses', $courses);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('subs.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'course_code'=>'required',
            'course_name'=>'required',
            'course_desc'=>'required',
        ]);

        $course = new Course;
        $course->course_code = $request->input('course_code');
        $course->course_name = $request->input('course_name');
        $course->course_desc = $request->input('course_desc');
        $course->save();

        return redirect('/subs')->with('success','New course added!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $course = Course::find($id);
        return view('subs.show')->with('course', $course);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $course = Course::find($id);
        return view('subs.edit')->with('course',$course);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'course_code'=>'required',
            'course_name'=>'required',
            'course_desc'=>'required',
        ]);

        $course = Course::find($id);
        $course->course_code = $request->input('course_code');
        $course->course_name = $request->input('course_name');
        $course->course_desc = $request->input('course_desc');
        $course->save();

        return redirect('/subs')->with('success','Course Updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $course = Course::find($id);
        $course->delete();

        return redirect('/subs')->with('success', 'Course successfully removed!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you two different databases?  or Two different tables in the single database?

Comment: two different tables in the same database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below code:

```
public function index()
{
    $records = User::all();
    $course = Course::all();
    return view('records.index', compact('records', 'course'));
}
```

View file like For your `if` Query

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Course Major</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if (count($records)>0)
        @foreach ($records as $record)
        @foreach ($course as $record)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$record->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$record->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$course->course_name}}</td> 
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @endforeach 
    @else
        <tr>
            <td  colspan="3"> No Record found!!</td>
        </tr>
    @endif
</tbody>     
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify `protected $connection` property in respective models.

The models you are using put database connection name in which that table exists.

Connection name is present in `database.php` file in `config` folder.

Like

```
  protected $connection = 'mysql_connection';
```

OR also directly specify connection name

```
 User::on('connection-name')->all();
```

Note
Instead of `$records = User::all(),Course::all();`

```
   $records_user = User::all();
   $records_course = Course::all();
```

Update

```
  return view('records.index')->with('records_user', $records_user)->with('records_course',$records_course);
```

Comment: will this make me able to access both tables from one controller?

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo there no any restriction on using number of models in one controller.

Comment: hence my question. how do i use them in one controller? is that the proper way i did in my `srcontroller`?

Comment: so now this is my index code in the controller

`public function index()
    {
        $records_user = User::all();
        $records_course = Course::all();
        return view('records.index')->with('records', $records_user)->with('records',$records_course);
    }`

Comment: and this is my blade code 
`@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @if (count($records_user)>0)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Course Major</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($records_user as $record)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$record->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$record->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$record->course_name}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    @else
 
    @endif
@endsection`

Comment: and im getting an error of  `Undefined variable: records_user (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sims\resources\views\records\index.blade.php)`. how can i fix that?

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo check updated answer and replace that line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202730/discussion-between-providence-moyo-and-prashant-deshmukh).